# Java JDBC not returning all rows from Database

Tags: java, sql-server

I am using a SQL Server stored procedure with a select statement

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GetProducts]
    @ProductType bigint
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT ProductsName 
    FROM tbl_Products WITH(NOLOCK)
    WHERE ProductType = @ProductType 
    ORDER BY ProductType DESC
END
```

For database return

```
ProductsName 
------------------
Apple
Orange
Honey
Watermelon
Table
Chair
Watch
Cup
```

For the JDBC part

```
Connection conn = null;
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connString);
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("{call dbo.sp_GetProducts(8)}");               
ResultSet resultSet = pstmt.executeQuery(); 
int size = 0;
while (resultSet.next()) {         
size = size + 1;
}
//End of program the size is only 2 instead of 8 (it only return Apple and Table)
```

I did an inspection in the SQL profile for the execution part, it also returned all 8 rows, but form the program resultset it only has 2 rows, what is the possible issue?

Comment: What's the ProductType for each ProductsName?

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc all same product type

Comment: execute "call dbo.sp_GetProducts(8)" directly from DB client tool you use. probably it will also return 8 records. check you java application connects to the same database that you  connects via you DB client tool

Comment: @hunter same db , and execute "call dbo.sp_GetProducts(8)" directly DB it return all the 8 record as above , but not from java application

Comment: [dbo].[sp_tbl_Prodcuts_Get]  I guess the typo has nothing to do with the issue

Comment: Don't you need to use [CallableStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/storedprocedures.html) to call stored procedure from JDBC?

Comment: CallableStatement cs, cs.registerOutParameter for the implicit cursor, cs.execute, and cs.getObject to get the resultSet.

Comment: **Side note**: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: See [Bad Habits to kick - putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere) - it is *not recommended* to use this everywhere - quite the contrary!